# Atomistic simulation and unit cell

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, simulations

Which cell type is most frequently used for atomistic simulations (vasp, abinit, etc): primitive unit cells, conventional unit cells or Wigner-Seitz primitive cells ? And, of course, why ?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish, no?

Comment: Regular calculations to obtain bulk properties of a crystal.

Comment: Generally one runs a simulation with as many atoms as needed to get a reasonable result. Which means you have to determine how many atoms you need, and what impact the crystal symmetry has on your simulation results. As far as I can tell, there are no hard-and-fast rules; one feels these things out.

Comment: @JonCuster could you make a response from your comments ?